# Button as input for html form

Tags: html

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward but I can't figure out how to code a form input that looks like a button.

I have a form like so:

[image]

I have tried using  but that seems to be more geared towards event drivers. I am effectively trying to have these be "toggle-able" so that selecting them adds them into the results of the form.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use radio button + label elements, and some  css

Answer (score 0):

You can give the submit buttons a name and value attribute, but only the clicked button’s value will be submitted.

Toggle-able html controls are checkboxes or radio buttons.

Comment: I just tried with the following:

<button class="mt-2 btn text-white btn-outline" data-bs-toggle="button" name="size" value="nano 1k-10k">nano 1k-10k</button>

however its not returning a value in my form POST

Comment: I meant `<button type="submit" name="size" value="nano 1k-10k">nano 1k-10k</button>`. You're trying to use bootstrap 5 toggle buttons. I'm not sure how those work. The documentation is unclear as to how their value would be added to the form. Maybe you need to manually loop over them and add hidden inputs in an onsubmit event handler.